# Searching for HD videos using the YouTube API v3?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am getting invalid combination of search filter error while retrieving the HD videos. this was the url - *https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=drama&videoDefinition=high&key={Developerkey}*

Error report

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.search",
    "reason": "invalidSearchFilter",
    "message": "Invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions.",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": ""
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions."
 }
}
```

Is it possible to retrieve HD videos? Please guide me. How can I get a response from this URL? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to include the `type=video` query parameter, since filtering on high definition only makes sense when the results are limited to videos.

That being said, the error message that's returned isn't actually helpful, and I'll ask the engineering team to revise it so that it clarifies what's wrong.